# React native TextInput isFocused method

Tags: react-native

I want to change background image dynamically.I tried to know TextInput is focused or not with this way.Also I tried `this.text.current.isFocused()`.But It didn't help me.Anyone knows?

```
text={};


renderDrawerContent(){
  let  image = this.text.isFocused() ?  require('../assets/images/gyzyl.png') : require('../assets/images/BlackBack.jpg');
        return(
            <Container style={styles.containerDrawer}>
               <ImageBackground
                source={image}
                style={{flex:1}}
                resizeMode={'cover'}
                 >

                   <Content style={{ paddingTop: 0, }}>
                       <View style={{paddingTop: 20}}>
                           <View style={{flexDirection:'column' , marginVertical:5 ,padding:15}}>
                               <Text style={styles.search}>Search</Text>
                               <TextInput ref={ref => this.text=ref} autotFocus={this.state.Focused} underlineColorAndroid={'white'} placeholder='Cinema, Theatre, Concert ...' placeholderTextColor = '#fff' style={{color: '#fff', fontSize: 16 ,flex:1 , borderBottomColor: '#fff'}} />
                           </View>
                       </View>

                   </Content>


                </ImageBackground>
            </Container>

        );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the onFocus event from textinput to do this along with onBlur.
Using this method you should add to your state object a value that tracks if the input is focused.

```
<TextInput onFocus={()=> this.setState({inputFocused: true})} onBlur={()=> this.setState({inputFocused: false})}/>
```

then just use your inputFocused to check if the input is focused or not

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that I got success.

```
 const [themeInput, setThemeInput] = useState(false)

     <TextInput
      mode='outlined' 
      theme={{colors: {primary: `${colors.salmon}`,  }}}
      onFocus={() =>setThemeInput(true)}
      onBlur={() =>setThemeInput(false)}
      label="Email"
      left={  <TextInput.Icon 
      name={() =>   <Feather name='mail' size={26} 
      color={ themeInput ? colors.salmon : colors.gray3} />} />}
     />
```